# How does one navigate back to their desired page on WP8 after having the app run in the background?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently writing a running tracker, and I want it to be possible for the user to have my application running in the background.

Everything is fine when running it in the background, but whenever I re-open the app, it puts me back at the main menu.

In the end, I want access to the RootFrame.BackStack, so that the user can pick up where they left off.

I tried the following code in my App.xaml.cs but it threw a "InvalidOperationException" at the attempt to access RootFrame.BackStack.GetEnumerator().Current.

Note: I checked, and all values before Current are non-null.

```
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        JournalEntry j;
        if (RootFrame.BackStack.GetEnumerator().Current != null)
            j = RootFrame.BackStack.GetEnumerator().Current;
        RunningInBackground = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Fast App Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Windows Phone 8 introduces the ability for apps to request that user
>   actions that would typically relaunch the app, such as tapping the
>   app’s Start Tile, instead resume the suspended instance of the
>   suspended app instance, if one exists. This feature is called Fast
>   Resume.

To enable Fast Resume for your app, add the ActivationPolicy attribute to the DefaultTask element in WMAppManifest.xml and set the value to “Resume”.

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice. Would you happen to know how to make it work more organically though? Simply changing "Resume" doesn't work, so I have to do a weird work-around and cancel navigation to my MainPage should the frame be reset.

This results is jittery page transitions.

Comment: Figured out my bug. Needed to sleep the thread for a second to allow the animation to play through.

Answer (score 0):

try this sample link. I hope this is what you are looking for.   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Fast-app-resume-backstack-f16baaa6